# MySQL Recommend an item.

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a query that for a selected person, it will recommend items based on their purchase history and what other people have bought who also bought that item.

Example:

```
Customer 1 purchases item A, and B.
Customer 2 purchases item B. 
Customer 2 is recommended, item A.
```

I have 4 tables that are used in this I will list them with the relevant row names.

```
Customer
PK: Cust_ID

Session
PK: Ses_ID
FK: Cust_ID

Order
PK: Order_ID
FK: ItemRef_ID
FK: Session_ID

Item
PK: Item_ID
```

I'm pretty new to SQL but here's what I've got so far, following that I really have no idea how to go about doing it.

Currently it only gives the items that the selected customer has bought 'Lani Morgan', but instead I'd like it to display items that other customers have bought, who have bought the item 'Lani Morgan' has bought.

```
SELECT Item_Desc, Item_ID 
FROM  rbickers.Item

LEFT JOIN rbickers.Order 
ON Item.Item_id = Order.itemref_id 

LEFT join rbickers.Session 
ON Order.Session_id = Session.Ses_id 

left join rbickers.customer
On customer.cust_ID = session.Cust_ID

Where Cust_First = "Lani" and Cust_Last = "Morgan"

GROUP BY Item_Type

LIMIT 10
```

Any help would really be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain, in more details, `but instead I'd like it to display items that other customers have bought, who have bought the item 'Lani Morgan' has bought` with sample data. Isn't `'Lani Morgan'` is a customer name from your query you posted??

Comment: Yeah that was my example. Essentially what I'm trying to do is similar to the Amazon recommended items section, but a more basic version.

So, if Lani Morgan for example has bought a toothbrush, someone else who bought that tooth brush, also bought some mouth wash and a bar of soap, the query will return, mouth wash and a bar of soap.

I understand that in the real world there is far more to it, (Nappies and beer scenario) but for now I'm just trying to get used to learning a new language and am struggling with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So by your basic version and with the supplied schema, the way I see it implemented is by checking for every item, if not bought by customer1, but bought by any other customer buying items customer1 has bought. 
Since this schema requires you to join through all of the given tables, I'd ask you to create a view of the join you've provided:

```
create view CustomerItems as 
SELECT *
FROM  rbickers.Item

LEFT JOIN rbickers.Order 
ON Item.Item_id = Order.itemref_id 

LEFT join rbickers.Session 
ON Order.Session_id = Session.Ses_id 

left join rbickers.customer
On customer.cust_ID = session.Cust_ID

#Where Cust_First = "Lani" and Cust_Last = "Morgan"
```

and then:

```
select distinct item.* from item, CustomerItems cust1 where 
cust1.Cust_First="Lani" and cust1.Cust_Last="Morgan" and 
item.Item_ID not in(
select Item_ID from CustomerItems cust2 where cust1.Cust_ID=cust2.Cust_ID) 
and exists(select * from CustomerItems cust3 where 
cust3.Cust_ID<>cust1.cust_ID and item.Item_ID=cust3.Item_ID);
```

Comment: That makes sense to me, but I can't get the threshhold part working as there are multiple selects in one query. Also, it is returning all the items, I think this is because of the threshhold though? I have instead put a limit of 3 on the cust1.Item_ID=cust2.Item_ID limit @threshold)); which makes me not so sure if this is the problem.

Comment: Fixed. You can use an equi-join instead of a left join. But I think that shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Okay, I'm still having a problem with this, it's saying Unknown column 'cust2.Cust_ID in'where clause' is cust2 a reference to a customer or all of the items?

Comment: Do check the viewname, I accidentally had put CustomerItems1 instead of CustomerItems